# Get Window Handle from Inspector

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-object-model, intptr, window-handles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open Event of Window and Handle of Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607807/open-event-of-window-and-handle-of-window)

Hello all,

How do I get a window handle (`IntPtr`) from the Outlook window I have just opened?

```
        OutLook.Items items = oFolder.Items;

        foreach (OutLook.MailItem mail in items)
        {

              mail.Display();

              //IntPtr a = (System.IntPtr)mail.GetInspector.Parent;
```

I am new to C sharp.

Comment: @Hans - not a duplicate but a sub of that question, this is trimmed down version to make it easier to answer. I think no one understood the previous question i.e. the wrong answer received. Secondly, I've read more about this and I now know that I need to get the window handle from the inspector. I've deleted the previous question now.

Comment: That was a more detailed question with an *answer*.  Flagging a moderator to get *this* question deleted.

Comment: there's no harm in asking follow-up questions, but re-posting the *same* question isn't good. Edit your existing question.